# Different water temperature in different faucets

Tags: water, temperature

I have my bathrooms remodeled and the temperature of the water is different in one bathroom than the other.

Even within the same bathroom, the bathtub is cooler than the water coming out of the sink.

Why could this be?

Thank you very much

Comment: It could have to do with different mixing valves in different bathrooms, or pressure control valves (like under a sink) being set differently. Could you add some details about what's warmer than what?

Answer (score 1):

Bathtub and shower valves have (and are required to have) anti-scald features which limit the temperature. Depending on the valve that may be somewhat adjustable - check the owners manual for it (look up on the web if you don't have one.)

I believe the reasoning is that a small child or invalid would not be able to get out of the tub, while it's assumed that they could pull their hands away from a sink. It is in response to actual burn incidents.